# Choropleth world map - convert k thousand numbers

Tags: r

When hovering over a country the numbers are shown as say 125.115k - I want to show it as 125,115
I tried using library(formattable) and something along the lines of z = comma(worldmap$Deaths,digits = 1)

My code is below

```
 output$World_Map <- renderPlotly({
            g <- list(
                showframe = FALSE,
                showcoastlines = FALSE,
                projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
            )
            plot_ly(
                worldmap,
                type = 'choropleth',
                locations = worldmap$COUNTRY_ALPHA_3_CODE,
                z = worldmap$Deaths, 
                text = paste("Number of Deaths: ",worldmap$COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME,"\n",comma(worldmap$Cases, digits = 0),"\n","Number of Cases: ",worldmap$COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME),
                colorscale = "Reds"
            ) %>% layout(title = "<b>Covid19 Global Pandemic .... Data Source: <a href='https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/'>Johns Hopkins University of Medicine</a><b>", geo = g)
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comma rendering numbers, I use `prettyNum` from base R, also comma function is available in scales package.

```
number_a <- 123456
prettyNum(number_a, big.mark = ",")
```

`[1] "123,456"`

Your question is about text tooltip in Plotly. You can do something like this, with hoverinfo/hovertemplate and text parameters.

Of course there are other manners to do it.

Because I don't have your data, I use an example from plotly website.

```
library(plotly)
# code for example
# https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries
# doc for hovertemplate
# https://plotly-r.com/controlling-tooltips.html#tooltip-text

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')

# light grey boundaries
l <- list(color = toRGB("grey"), width = 0.5)

# specify map projection/options
g <- list(
  showframe = FALSE,
  showcoastlines = FALSE,
  projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
)

fig <- plot_geo(df)
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  z = ~GDP..BILLIONS., color = ~GDP..BILLIONS., colors = 'Blues',
  locations = ~CODE, marker = list(line = l), 
  hoverinfo = "text",
  text = ~glue::glue("{COUNTRY} <b>{CODE}</b>"),
  hovertemplate = "%{z:,0f}<extra>%{text}</extra>"
)
fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = 'GDP Billions US$', tickformat = ",0f")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = '2014 Global GDP<br>Source:<a href="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2195.html">CIA World Factbook</a>',
  geo = g
)

fig
```

[image: Example image]

With this you can easily configure your hover info / tooltip.

See here for more examples :
https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/#customize-choropleth-chart

For French number (space instead of comma), you can at the end config locale:

```
fig %>%
  config(locale = 'fr')
```

[image: French numbers formatting]

Comment: Hi - thanks for this and now works just fine. Many Thanks

Comment: Hi - nice; thanks for your feedback. If ok for you you can mark this question as answered or vote as you want, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).